# How to use mapfragment in a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

Mainly i got a FragmentActivity with a drop down menu that once you choose an item from that menu it makes my private class that extends Fragment to show every time other things on the map it self
Now the problem is that when i make the line inside the fragment class that controls the map :

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap()
```

It says you cant cast fragment to MapFragment so i tried to extend the MapFragment for the class but when i choose an item inside the dropdown menu i do this section of the code :

```
Fragment fragment = new MyFragmentClass()();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(PlacesFinder.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
fragment.setArguments(args);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

i can only use fragment so how can i use the google map inside the fragment  if i cant findview it inside the fragment class and cant extends mapfragment because of the dropdown menu?

Thanks head up :)

Comment: Having trouble understanding your question. Is the issue using `MapFragment` within a fragment?

Comment: The problem is that i want to use a GoogleMap object inside a fragment but i need to use the MapFragment because i got a lyaout  of a fragment :
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
that i use
but i dont know how to relate it inside a fragment class to the MapFragment

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GoogleMap` inside a fragment. Looking at just the part of your code that creates the fragment in XML there are errors. Assuming this fragment is the only element in your XML layout this is how it should read:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/map" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"      
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

The last line of your XML, where you have android:name is wrong. You code adding the map within the activity should work

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I have used this code below with no problems before

```
mapFrag = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmenManager().findFragmenById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

The only difference is (1) I was using a `SupportMapFragment`; (2) I declared my `GoogleMap` outside of `onCreate`.

It sounds to be based on what you're describing with the fragment not being able to be cast to the right class that this is an issue either with the error in the fragment XML or you are not using the right imports. If you are using `MapFragment` then you need make sure you're using the `MapFragment` import (not `SupportMapFragment` or just `Fragment`).

As to the last part of you're code I'm not sure what the relationship with the dropdown menu is. It looks like you're passing arguments to a fragment? If you can provide more details I will comment on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay but This is the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener , LocationListener{
    private String [] types;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    public static GoogleMap map = null;
    public static boolean googlePlayOn = false;
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        types = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.values);
        googlePlayOn = isGooglePlay();
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
        // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBarThemedContextCompat(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, types), this);
    }

    /**
     * This function checks in the phone operating system that 
     * the phone got google play services
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isGooglePlay()
    {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
            return true;
        else
            ((Dialog) GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10)).show();
        return false;
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private Context getActionBarThemedContextCompat() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            return getActionBar().getThemedContext();
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                    savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Serialize the current dropdown position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
                .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
        // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
        // container view.
        if(position != PlacesFinder.currentTitle)
        {
            if(!PlacesFinder.created)
            {
                PlacesFinder.created = true;
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt(PlacesFinder.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
                Fragment fragment = new PlacesFinder();
                fragment.setArguments(b);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
            }
            PlacesFinder.newTitleBeenChosenHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        return true;
    }



    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class PlacesFinder extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static boolean created = false;
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public static Handler newTitleBeenChosenHandler;
        public static int currentTitle = 0;
        private Context context;
        public PlacesFinder() {
            this.context = getActivity();
            loadMapFragment();
        }
        private void loadMapFragment()
        {
            if(googlePlayOn)
            {
                if(map == null)
                    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.places_fragment, container , false);
        }


    }



    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}




This is the main xml file :
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

This is the mapfragment file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Once i do the line of code 
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

the apps fails and it says i got a null pointer and i dont have a clue why...

Answer (score 0):

You should use getSupportFragmentManager().

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

As you're using FragmentActivity, this should work. I'm facing the same problem although I'm using Fragment and that won't do it :(